# run a cmd command as administrator via context menu on windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, contextmenu

I need some help: I want to create an explorer context menu option(while right clicking on a folder) for my program to run it as administrator from the context menu by using this .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Choose the correct command processor for the current operating system
SET _cmd=
:: Variable to add shortcut to menu entry (NT only,
:: since COMMAND.COM cannot echo an ampersand)
SET _=
ECHO.%COMSPEC% | FIND /I "command.com" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET _cmd=command.com /e:4096
ECHO.%COMSPEC% | FIND /I "cmd.exe" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET _cmd=cmd.exe
IF [%_cmd%]==[cmd.exe] SET _=^&
:: Create a temporary .REG file
> %TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO REGEDIT4
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO.
:Print
ECHO Adding "Explorer context menu option" entry
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ourprog]
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO @="%_%Add to Hot Backup (A.A.T Anti-Ransomware)"
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO.
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ourprog\command]
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO @="java -jar C:\users\Tamir Naaman\Desktop\A.A.T-Anti-Ransomware.jar -backup \"%%L\"
>>%TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG ECHO.
:: If neither COMMAND.COM nor CMD.EXE then skip this step
IF [%_cmd%]==[] GOTO Merge
:: Merge the temporary .REG file
:Merge
START /WAIT REGEDIT /S %TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG
:: Delete the temporary .REG file
DEL %TEMP%.\DEFOPEN.REG
:: Ready
GOTO End
:: Clean up variables and quit
:End
SET _cmd=
SET _=
```

and I got this error message after I tried to click the option in the context menu:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idga6.png)

The registry picture:

[Registry picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aZGg.png)

The registry picture:

[Registry picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaAey.png)

I just noticed  that the default value is not set, how can i fix my code?

Can you help me find the problem in my batch file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Start by navigating to the registry command key, right-clicking to modify the default value and copying/pasting the exact and entire content of the value data into your question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51656101/edit).

Comment: I added a picture of my registry  with the command folder open, and i just noticed that the value is not set.

Answer (score 4):

**Registry settings for 'Directory Shell Context Menu Command' to be executed As Administrator**

For a context menu command to be executed As Administrator(Elevated) you have to put the command under the special verb `RunAs` like: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\runas\command]`

For directories, this special verb is usually unused, but you can never be sure about that, so using is not recommended at all.

The alternate recommended option is to use [Static Cascading Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/creating-static-cascading-menus), which has been introduced starting from Windows 7. With them, the context menu can be fully isolated with its own private `RunAs` verb.

A sample registry script leveraging Cascading Menus would be

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\shell\\AATCascade"
"MUIVerb"="A.A.T Anti-Ransomware"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"MUIVerb"="Add to Hot Backup"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade\shell\runas\command]
@="java.exe -jar \"C:\\Users\\Tamir Naaman\\Desktop\\A.A.T-Anti-Ransomware.jar\" -backup \"%V\""
```

You have to make sure that the location of `java.exe` is defined in the `PATH` environment variable or specify the full path to `java.exe`

The advantage of *Cascading Menus* is that you can add as many commands as you need (with custom verbs other than `RunAs`) and keep all of them under the root cascading menu resulting in a more user friendly and much cleaner context menu.

Under each sub menu there could be only one `RunAs` verb, So if there are more menu item command that needs elevation you have to elevate them by other means. And `PowerShell` can used for that task: `PowerShell.exe -Command Start-Process "PathToExecutable" 'ExecutableParameters' -Verb RunAs`

It is even possible to create nested cascading menus to keep the menu items more organized when you want add many more sub items and each sub menu can have its own `RunAs` verb.

After you have done testing the registry script then you can move on to the next step and adopt the registry script for importing from a batch file.

**Embedding the registry script into a batch file**

Three methods can be used each with its own pros and cons:

- Converting the registry script to individual `REG.EXE ADD` commands. The advantage is that you don't need to escape the backslash(`\`) and double quotes(`"`) like what is seen in registry scripts and it is more flexible in configuring the registry settings at runtime e.g. Determining the the location of the supporting files at runtime and adjusting the registry setting accordingly. But the conversion process is tedious and error-prone. Although there are tools out there than can automate the task and quickly convert a registry script to a batch file.
- Writing the registry script to a temporary file at runtime using the `echo` commands like what you have done(with errors and mistakes of course). It provides some level of flexibility in adjusting the registry script at runtime with the help of environment variables, but you have to preserve the escaped syntax of the original registry script and also be careful about special characters in batch and escape them too. For small scripts this is not a problem but for bigger ones it gets out of management very quickly.

The batch script:

```
@echo off
(
    echo REGEDIT4
    echo,
    echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade]
    echo "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\shell\\AATCascade"
    echo "MUIVerb"="A.A.T Anti-Ransomware"
    echo "HasLUAShield"=""
    echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade\shell\runas]
    echo "HasLUAShield"=""
    echo "MUIVerb"="Add to Hot Backup"
    echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\AATCascade\shell\runas\command]
    echo @=^"java.exe -jar \"C:\\Users\\Tamir Naaman\\Desktop\\A.A.T-Anti-Ransomware.jar\" -backup \"%%V\"^"
)>"%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"

:: First try to import the registry script by REG.EXE to avoid unnecessary elevation if possible.
:: In case all the base keys are HKEY_CURRENT_USER no elevation is required.
REG IMPORT "%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG" 2>nul || REGEDIT /S "%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"
del "%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"
```

- The last method is to copy paste the registry script at the end the following batch script. The advantage is that no special handling is required and the reg script can used as is. The disadvantage is that the registry script is static and batch script will not have control over the contents at runtime, it will be imported as it is.

Self Importer BAT/REG Script:

```
:: SelfImporter BAT/REG Script
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TIME="
set "id=%TIME: =0%"
call :getBatFileInfo @f0 @nx0
set "id=%@nx0%.%id:~0,2%%id:~3,2%%id:~6,2%%id:~-2%"
set "RegFile=%TEMP%\RegImport.%id%.reg.tmp"
(
    echo REGEDIT4
    echo,
    type "%@f0%"
)>"%RegFile%" && (
    echo Importing registry script...
    REG IMPORT "%RegFile%" 2>nul || REGEDIT /S "%RegFile%"
    del "%RegFile%"
)
pause
goto :EOF
:getBatFileInfo <f0> <nx0>
set "%~1=%~f0" & set "%~2=%~nx0" & exit /b
<End of batch script>
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

The rest the registry script goes here
.
.
```

And at last you can just save your batch scripts with `.CMD` extension and forget about `COMMAND.COM`

Answer (score -1):

To get the information I'm assuming you wanted into the registry your script should probably look a little more like this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
(   ECHO REGEDIT4
    ECHO(
    ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\ourprog]
    ECHO @="Add to Hot Backup (A.A.T Anti-Ransomware)"
    ECHO(
    ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\ourprog\command]
    ECHO @="java -jar \"C:\\Users\\Tamir Naaman\\Desktop\\A.A.T-Anti-Ransomware.jar\" -backup \"%%V\""
    ECHO()>"%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"
REGEDIT /S "%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"
DEL "%TEMP%\DEFOPEN.REG"
```

It is your responsibility to ensure that the `java` command without specifying a full path will work fine in the target environment.

*You will note that I have used the user key, because using the a key for every user on the PC is unnecessary especially when the jar file is located within a specific users profile tree*

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer i tried your code and it wrote me the error message : "application not found"

Comment: @tna, that's not my problem, the code I've provided is correct. As I stated, it's your responsibility to ensure that the paths and commands etc. are correct for your target environment. I'm not at your PC and unable to fix information you did not provide and which is unavailable to me.

Comment: its because i need to run it as administrator and to send it the current path file as parameter

Comment: Please also note that `REGEDIT4` is really old, you should probably be using `ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` as the header instead.

Comment: Ok thank you , is it possible that i see the error "Application not found" because my program is not running as administrator ?

Comment: when i execute the same command via cmd as administrator it works but without there is the access denied error

Comment: @tna, once you've determined the correct commandline to run your `java` command as administrator, update me and I'll adjust my registry code above to match. _I do not have a Windows computer, nevermind a Windows 10 one, ruined with a java installation. I rarely have the opportunity to test or investigate things pre or post answer_.

Comment: thank you very much , you helped me a lot , now I just need to find out how to run it as administrator

Comment: if someone else can also help me please

Comment: @tna, it is your responsibility to research and provide the command, this is a coding help site, if you don't know how to run your command As administrator, what was the point jumping in with both feet and creating a context menu entry for it? I'll repeat, you only need to determine the command to run 'as administrator'/'elevated' your `java` command with parameters and I'll translate it accordingly into my answer above.

Comment: I tried all of that already I wrote it in my question at the beginning

Comment: @tna, _I cannot believe that nobody on this site has ever asked about running a java command elevated_, did you search at all? _I would also think that the proper way to do this would be for required elevation to be built into the program itself._

Comment: hi i tried again i executed this command in cmd (in cmd as administrator it works) to run my program as administrator : "powershell -Command "java -jar \"C:\Users\Tamir Naaman\Desktop\A.A.T-Anti-Ransomware.jar\" -backup -FolderArgument -Verb RunAs"" but it didnt worked i tried a lot of combinations but still it doesnt work it just keep telling me access denied is there any other way to run this as administrator ??